Hash security and penentration testing
I've been looking at hash security, and how tools like hashcat and John The Ripper work. I seem to have misunderstood some basic stuff, and would appreciate some clarification on:

If you're pen testing, and you've got a hash that you're trying to get a plain password from, how exactly are you meant to have found that hash? Is it is assumed that you're already on the target system and can simply read /etc/shadow/whatever? Or is it assumed to have been snooped from plain HTTP, in which case when would ever find a hash, rather than a plain password, on HTTP?
Various sources on the web make the point that you can't do dictionary or rainbow attacks without the salt. But when would you ever have a hash which doesn't actually include the salt in plaintext anyway? Surely, in practical cases, if you have a hash, you also have the salt?
If you've got the salt, what's to stop you from just constructing your own rainbow tables?


This question is probably more about information security in general rather than specifically cryptography, so I think the question would get a better response on that site security.stackexchange.com

@n-l-i : thanks - I didn't know about the security site; I've asked there.



If you're pen testing, and you've got a hash that you're trying to get a plain password from, how exactly are you meant to have found that hash? Is it is assumed that you're already on the target system and can simply read /etc/shadow/whatever?


Well, yes, they're either on the system, have access to a backup, bribed a sysadmin, or got it some other way.  The point really is that the security of the system shouldn't depend solely on how well that file is protected.

Or is it assumed to have been snooped from plain HTTP, in which case when would ever find a hash, rather than a plain password, on HTTP?

If you're silly enough to use unencrypted HTTP to login, they don't need to recover the original - they can login by simply repeating the hashed password that was sent.
[I'm omitting question 2 because I don't quite understand what you're asking]


If you've got the salt, what's to stop you from just constructing your own rainbow tables?


Nothing; except that building a rainbow table from scratch is actually more expensive than hashing values from your dictionary.  The value in a rainbow table is that it can be used multiple times - except, if you include the salt, the rainbow table you build will be usable only with that salt value (and hence, realistically, you're never be able to use it again).
(Or, you could try to build a rainbow table that includes the potential passwords and all possible salt values - that makes the range of possibilities the rainbow table attempts to cover much larger, which means that it's far more expensive to build).
